# Does pragma around function affect inner functions

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, pragma

Say I have my program compiled with O2 and just

```
#pragma GCC push_options  
#pragma GCC optimize("O0")  
my_func  
{  
    other_func();  
}  
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Does pragma also affect other_func in any way?

Thanks

Comment: How could it affect `other_func`? It is just a call. The settings for `other_func` are determined by the pragmas and compiler settings at the place where `other_func` is defined, that is where its body is implemented.

Comment: That's what I thought aswell. Found no info on this however. Thanks

Comment: With the `push_options` and `pop_options` you create a local "scope" for the `optimize` pragma, [see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas). That is, only the functions after the `optimze` pragma, but before you restore the old settings with `pop_options` should be compiled with optimization level 0.

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect other_func() as it is a jmp instruction here in assamble。